# I wonder is there a Mandarin term for " jump the shark"

Tags: translation, equivalent-phrase

I wonder is there a Mandarin term for " jump the shark" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumping_the_shark which means the decline of quality of a T.V show reached the breaking point for the viewers, even the most loyal fans have no choice but give up on the show.

My guess would be 沒救了，

> The T.V show 'House' finally jumped the shark. (電視劇 「醫神」終於沒救了。)

but is there other choices?

I am a native Cantonese speaker, there might be some mainland term I am not aware of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should be "江郞才尽"

"江郎才尽" means someone was always writing good articles, but one day, his article is not that good anymore.

Comment: Yes, that's a good choice, 'House' was great the first two seasons. the writing quality went down from then on, the last season was painfully bad,  " The writers of the show had been 江郎才尽"

Comment: Oh, well, I didn't think it went downhill quite that bad, but yeah, it was a disappointment from Season 4 on.  The intern reality show was the "jump-the-shark" moment for House.  Although, I did like the series finale all right. ¶ Oh, and +1, I quite like this choice.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think of is "完蛋了"

Comment: 完蛋了 is quite general, I am hoping to learn a term specifically for T.V   drama. The term  " jump the shark" is similar  to" the final straw", but  "jump the shark" refers to T.V show's bad writing only. I can accept the fact that there's no equivalent  in Mandarin and consider this question closed.